# Dar color a la mitad del borde con css

Tags: css, css3

Tengo que hacer un panel y en ciertas esquinas tengo que formar una tipo L como se muestra en la figura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este código CSS:

```
.panel
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD),
                    linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD),
                    linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD),
                    linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD);           
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px 38%, 15% 10px, 10px 38%, 15% 10px, calc(100% - 8px) calc(100% - 8px);
    background-position: left bottom, left bottom, right top, right top, 4px 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Hasta el momento lo que tengo es que me forma la L correctamente pero la coloca dentro del panel y no como se ve en la imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo que haría sería jugar con el :before y el :after del panel:

```
 .panel{
position: relative;
/*resto de codigo */
}

.panel::before,
.panel::after{
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #ff0000;
content: ' ';
}

panel::before{
bottom: -10px;
left: -10px;
}

panel::after{
top: -10px;
right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Se me olvidó comentarte que juegues con los z-index de :before y :after para posicionarlo detrás del contenido del panel. Con esto consigues el efecto que quieres

Answer (score 0):

bueno podrias hacerlo agregando otro `div` dentro

ejemplo:

```css
body{
    background-color: #00ffd9;
}
.panel{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    /* background-color: #fff;*/
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD),
                    linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD),
                    linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD),
                    linear-gradient(#4848CD, #4848CD);           
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px 38%, 15% 10px, 10px 38%, 15% 10px, calc(100% - 8px) calc(100% - 8px);
    background-position: left bottom, left bottom, right top, right top, 4px 4px;
   /*  padding: 10px; */
    height: 400px;
}


.inside{
    margin:10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
   <div class="inside"></div> 
</div>
```